# WHERE in (subquery) clause yii

Tags: mysql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a `mysql` query like this

```
 (SELECT 
    `notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, `event`.`title` as sourceName,concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName
 FROM 
    `notification` 
 INNER JOIN 
    `event` 
 ON 
     event.id = notification.source_id 
 INNER JOIN 
     `user` as v
 ON 
      v.id = notification.user_id 
 AND 
      notification.activity_type = "checkin" 
 where 
      user_id in 
      (SELECT friend.friend_id from friend WHERE friend.user_id=1 AND friend.is_active=1)) 
 UNION 
(SELECT 
      `notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, concat_ws(" ",u.firstname,u.lastname) as sourceName,concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName 
 FROM 
      `notification` 
 INNER JOIN 
      `user` as u 
 ON 
       u.id = notification.source_id 
 INNER JOIN 
      `user` as v ON v.id = notification.user_id 
 AND 
       notification.activity_type = "friend" 
 where user_id in 
       (SELECT friend.friend_id from friend WHERE friend.user_id=1 AND friend.is_active=1) )
```

And i want to write that query in `yii2` and i dont know how to write subquery in `where` in clause.

So far i have done this

```
$query2 ->select(['notification.id', 'notification.user_id AS user_id', 'notification.activity_type', 'notification.source_id', 'concat_ws(" ",u.firstname,u.lastname) as sourceName','concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName','user_image.imagepath as image'])
            ->from('notification' )
            ->innerJoin('user as u', 'u.id = notification.source_id')
            ->innerJoin('user_image','user_image.user_id = notification.user_id')
            ->innerJoin('user as v', 'v.id = notification.user_id AND notification.activity_type = "friend"')
            ->where('user_image.imagetype="profile"')
            ->andWhere(['user_id'=>('SELECT friend.friend_id from friend WHERE friend.user_id='.$id.' AND friend.is_active=1')]);

$query  ->select(['notification.id','notification.user_id AS user_id','notification.activity_type', 'notification.source_id', 'event.title as sourceName','concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName','organiser.image as image'])
            ->from('notification')
            ->innerJoin('event', 'event.id = notification.source_id')
            ->innerJoin('organiser','organiser.organiser_id = event.organiser_id')
            ->innerJoin('user as v', 'v.id = notification.user_id AND notification.activity_type = "checkin"')
            ->Where(['in', 'user_id', [488,489]])
            ->union($query2);
```

Which generates the command query like this

```
(SELECT 
    `notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, `event`.`title` AS `sourceName`, concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName, `organiser`.`image` AS `image` 
FROM 
    `notification` 
INNER JOIN 
    `event` 
ON 
     event.id = notification.source_id 
INNER JOIN 
    `organiser`
ON   
     organiser.organiser_id = event.organiser_id 
INNER JOIN 
     `user` `v` 
ON 
     v.id = notification.user_id 
AND 
      notification.activity_type = "checkin" 
WHERE 
     `user_id` IN (:qp0, :qp1))
UNION 
( SELECT 
     `notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, concat_ws(" ",u.firstname,u.lastname) as sourceName, concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName, `user_image`.`imagepath` AS `image` 
FROM 
     `notification` 
INNER JOIN 
     `user` `u` 
ON 
      u.id = notification.source_id 
INNER JOIN 
      `user_image` 
ON 
       user_image.user_id = notification.user_id 
INNER JOIN 
      `user` `v` 
ON 
       v.id = notification.user_id 
AND 
       notification.activity_type = "friend" 
WHERE 
      (user_image.imagetype="profile") AND (`user_id`=:qp2) )
```

But its not working,so what is the right syntax
and also feel free to give suggestion if `where` in could be write with `inner join`

that would make it very easy to write query

thank you

Comment: what error r u getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This




$query = (new Query())
            ->select('notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, `event`.`title` as sourceName,concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName')
            ->from('notification')
            ->innerJoin('event' ,'event.id = notification.source_id')
            ->innerJoin('user v' ,'v.id = notification.user_id')
            ->where([
                'user_id' => (new Query())
                    ->select('friend.friend_id')
                    ->from('friend')
                    ->where([
                        'friend.user_id' => 1,
                        'friend.is_active' => 1
                    ])
            ])->andWhere([
                'notification.activity_type' => "checkin"
            ]);

        $query2 = (new Query())
            ->select('`notification`.`id`, `notification`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `notification`.`activity_type`, `notification`.`source_id`, concat_ws(" ",u.firstname,u.lastname) as sourceName,concat_ws(" ",v.firstname,v.lastname) as ActorName')
            ->from('notification')
            ->innerJoin('user v' ,'v.id = notification.user_id')
            ->where([
                'user_id' => (new Query())
                    ->select('friend.friend_id')
                    ->from('friend')
                    ->where([
                        'friend.user_id' => 1,
                        'friend.is_active' => 1
                    ])
            ])->andWhere([
                'notification.activity_type' => "checkin"
            ])->union($query)->all();
```

Comment: i also wants to add `limit` and `offset` at the end of query.. i mean i want to set limit for total result set of those both query.. how can i do that???

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yii2 [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html), here is an example.

```
$subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())->select([
                  'users.id as userId', 
                  'users.first_name', 
                  'users.username',
                  'users.last_name', 
                  'users.sector_id',
              ])
              ->from(['users'])
              ->where(['=', 'role_id', 3])
              ->orWhere(['=', 'role_id', 2])
              ->groupBy('users.id');

$query =  (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['user.*', 'user_address.*'])
            ->from(['user'=>$subQuery])
            ->leftJoin('user_address', 'user.userId = user_address.user_id')
            ->where(['between', 'latitude', $min_lat, $max_lat])
            ->andWhere(['between', 'longitude', $min_lon, $max_lon])
            ->groupBy('user.userId');
```